# moving the content at the end of a table row

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, cell

I'm having this issues with the below table in which I want to set the 'view book' link and reserved to be the last in the row, but apparently the x = TABLE_ROW.insertCell(-1) is not working.

I just want to have the link/span at the end of the table row. Shouldn't the -1 argument be enough for this?

Can you please help me identifying what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var data = {
  "headings": {
    "propBook": "Book",
    "propAuthor": "Author",
    "propYear": "Year",
  },
  "items": [{
      "fields": {
        "propBook": "The Great Gatsby",
        "propAuthor": "F Scott Fitzgerald",
        "propYear": "1925",
      },
      "button": {
        "name": "View book",
        "propURL": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "propBook": "The Grapes of Wrath",
        "propAuthor": "John Steinbeck",
        "propYear": "1939",
      },
      "button": {
        "name": "View book",
        "propURL": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "propBook": "A Wild Sheep Chase",
        "propAuthor": "Haruki Murakami",
        "propYear": "1982",
      },
      "button": {
        "name": "View book",
        "propURL": "https://google.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}


const HEADINGS = data.headings;
const ITEMS = data.items;
const TABLE_WRAPPER = document.querySelector('.book-component .table-wrapper');
const TABLE = document.createElement('table');
TABLE.setAttribute('class', 'pagination');
TABLE_WRAPPER.appendChild(TABLE);


for (const field in data) {
  const TABLE_ROW = document.createElement('tr');
  TABLE_ROW.setAttribute('id', 'myRow');

  if (field == 'headings') {
    for (const child in HEADINGS) {
      const HEADER_CELL = document.createElement('th');
      TABLE_ROW.appendChild(HEADER_CELL);
      HEADER_CELL.setAttribute('class', 'sort-cta');
      HEADER_CELL.innerText = HEADINGS[child];
      TABLE.appendChild(TABLE_ROW);
    }
  } else if (field == 'items') {
    for (const child in ITEMS) {
      const TABLE_ROW = document.createElement('tr');
      let item = ITEMS[child].fields;
      let btn = ITEMS[child].button;
      if (btn.propURL !== '') {
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', btn.propURL);
        link.innerHTML = btn.name;
        x = TABLE_ROW.insertCell(-1);
        x.appendChild(link);
      } else {
        let link = document.createElement('span');
        link.innerHTML = 'Reserved';
        x = TABLE_ROW.insertCell(-1);
        x.appendChild(link);
      }

      for (const row in item) {
        const TABLE_DATA = document.createElement('td');
        TABLE_ROW.appendChild(TABLE_DATA);
        TABLE_DATA.innerText = item[row];
        TABLE.appendChild(TABLE_ROW);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
tr.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.pager {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.pager-item.selected {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #0077cc;
  background: #0077cc;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-component">
  <div class="table-wrapper">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just should inset cell data first. Then insert the link cell at the end of a table row.

http://jsfiddle.net/u1bvq376/

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
for (const field in data) {
  const TABLE_ROW = document.createElement('tr');
  TABLE_ROW.setAttribute('id', 'myRow');

  if (field == 'headings') {
    for (const child in HEADINGS) {
      const HEADER_CELL = document.createElement('th');
      TABLE_ROW.appendChild(HEADER_CELL);
      HEADER_CELL.setAttribute('class', 'sort-cta');
      HEADER_CELL.innerText = HEADINGS[child];
      TABLE.appendChild(TABLE_ROW);
    }
  } else if (field == 'items') {
    for (const child in ITEMS) {
      const TABLE_ROW = document.createElement('tr');
      let item = ITEMS[child].fields;
      let btn = ITEMS[child].button;      

    // insert the cell data first
      for (const row in item) {
        const TABLE_DATA = document.createElement('td');
        TABLE_ROW.appendChild(TABLE_DATA);
        TABLE_DATA.innerText = item[row];
        TABLE.appendChild(TABLE_ROW);       
      }
      
      // then insert the link
      if (btn.propURL !== '') {
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', btn.propURL);
        link.innerHTML = btn.name;
        x = TABLE_ROW.insertCell(-1);
        x.appendChild(link);
      } else {
        let link = document.createElement('span');
        link.innerHTML = 'Reserved';
        x = TABLE_ROW.insertCell(-1);
        x.appendChild(link);
      }
    }
  }
}
```